# How do you send an actionable (rich) notification using Firebase upstream messaging?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to make a firebase upstream message delivered as an actionable notification? This is what I am trying to accomplish : I want to be able to send an actionable upstream firebase message from my iPad to my iPhone.

Is this possible?

Here is what my code currently looks like. I am able to successfully send the remote notification and the iPhone receives it. I have tried many different things to get it to send an actionable notification but nothing seems to work.

```
let Category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "MESSAGE",
      actions: [],
      intentIdentifiers: [],
      options: .customDismissAction)


    let snoozeAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "EMERGENCY_MESSAGE_ACTION",
      title: "Are you ok?",
      options: UNNotificationActionOptions(rawValue: 0))



    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.setNotificationCategories([Category])


    let serverKey = "MY_SERVER_KEY"

    let topic = ""
    let url = URL(string: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")

     let postParams = [
        "to": "RECIEVING_DEVICE_TOKEN","mutable_content":true,


    "notification": [
            "body" : "\(emergencyMessage.text!)",
            "title" : "EMERGENCY!",
            "sound" : "alert.aiff", // or specify audio name to play
        "message_id": "12345"
        ],


    "data":[
    "apns":[
    "payload": [
    "aps": [
        "category": "MESSAGE"
        ]
        ]
        ]
]








]


        as [String : Any]




    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("key=\(serverKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")



    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postParams, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions())
        print("My paramaters: \(postParams)")
    } catch {
        print("Caught an error: \(error)")
    }



    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        if let realResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            if realResponse.statusCode != 200 {
                print("Not a 200 response")
            }
        }

        if let postString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as String? {
            print("POST: \(postString)")
        }
        }

        .resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Upstream messages aren't sent from one device directly to another.  They're sent [from a device to an app server you control](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/upstream).  You app server must implement the [XMPP protocol defined in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref).  At your server, you will have to figure out how to send another message to the other device.

Comment: Doug, thank you for the response! This is my current code, I am able to send a message from my iPad to my iPhone. How can I make this send an actionable notification?

Comment: That's not really code.  That's just a JSON object.  I can't tell what you're doing with it.

Comment: Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you're embedding admin credentials directly into your app, which is highly insecure.  Anyone can reverse engineer your app, get a hold of that key, and access your project with admin privileges.  You really should move that out of your app an into a backend you control.

Comment: OK, I will do that. How can I make this send an actionable notification?